# How do I configure ftp to where i can access all of my server files?

Tags: vsftpd

I recently bought a VPS because I am working on a project for building a website with a heavy focus on server side scripting. I just installed vsftpd and configured it with anonymous access temporarily to see if it would work. I connect perfectly, however none of my server files or directories that I see in the shell are showing up in my ftp directory listing. Why is this happening and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your anonymous root directory?
Add this to /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
anon_root=/your/directory/
```

If this is already set properly my next suggestion would be check permissions.

Comment: I want it to be in the root directory, or in other words, I want the anon (at least for now) root folder to be the root folder of the vps. I added "anon_root=/root" but that did nothing.

Comment: @ripjerry **OUCH!  Don't do that!  Huge security hole!**  For an internal server to share files on your LAN, no problem.  Read about chroot in the docs.  **For an internet-facing server, take it off-line now before it's used as a pr0n server!**

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue from the sound of it.  Also, I am going to second Fappy on this really not sounding like a good idea.  Why don't you configure sshd and then use sftp at the least.  It is rather simple and you should be able to access it using pretty much any common ftp/sftp client.

  I would strongly recommend looking at sshd before allowing your anonymous ftp login root access.  This is essentially giving the entire internet complete control of your computer.